# How do I write a DAX measure that allows me to make a chart that compares the date with intervals for data rows?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a following table:

[image]

I want to create a chart with dates on X axis, and with total values of *active* items on Y axis. *Active* means, that a given chart date is greater than "Date start" and smaller than "Date start" + "Duration in days".

I have trouble creating a measure that would calculate that.

Comment: Please paste your sample data as copiable text.

Answer (score 0):

> I have trouble creating a measure that would calculate that.

This, like many things you *might* fix with a clever DAX measure, is better solved by fixing your data model so that building the report is easy.  That is, in fact, what makes a data model good or bad.

So transform the data into a table that has one row per day per item.  Then it's simple.

Answer (score 0):

+1 about fixing the appropriate data model

That been said, I would do the following to solve this:

- create a connected date table to be used as the x-axis in your chart
- create another, not connected, date table to serve as slicer to pick your date
- create the measure as you described using the date from the second date table to compare with and to filter against (vs. start date and vs. start date + duration, respectively)

Good luck!

Comment: @Michael: have you been able to solve it?